# What does the 好きな do in this sentence?

Tags: translation

This is an extract I am trying to translate

> 次期族長に期待されているが
>   村の外の話を聞くことが好きな
>   好奇心旺盛な側面もあるようだ。

From my understanding and the posts I have read here, 好きな means "favorite" or "which one likes". But I don't understand how it works in this whole sentence, or how it connects to the said person having a side of him that is filled with curiosity.

Answer (score 7):

> 次期族長{じきぞくちょう}に期待{きたい}されているが
>
> 村{むら}の外{そと}の話{はなし}を聞{き}くことが好{す}きな
>
> 好奇心旺盛{こうきしんおうせい}な側面{そくめん}もあるようだ。

「好き**な**」 is the 連体形{れんたいけい}  ("attributive form") of the na-adjective 「好き」.  What that means is that it modifies a ***noun***.

In this sentence, both

「村の外の話を聞くことが好き**な**」 and 「好奇心旺盛**な**」 are adjectival phrases that modify the noun 「側面」 ("side, aspect").  Thus, this person seems to have that aspect （あるようだ） described by the two phrases above.

Hope you are following all this.  Since you are new here, I have no idea how much Japanese you already know.

> "[The unmentioned subject], who is expected to become the next chief/leader seems to have a side filled with curiosity, loving to hear/learn about the world outside of the village."