# What does "好きなだけ" mean here?

Tags: grammar, particles, usage

Is な used to connect 好き and だけ. Does it mean that she only likes reading books?

```
わたしは本を読むのが好きなだけの極々虚弱な女の子だ。
```

Comment: Should be a dup of [What does the 好きな do in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/74273) And yes, it means "she only likes reading books"

Comment: @sundowner This seems a bit different from the suggested duplicate.  While the sentence does make sense to me, I can't quite parse how  好きなだけの is working.  Clearly this の is what is connecting the previous phrase with what's following.  But where's the noun?  So, like the OP, I'm wondering whether だけ is being used as a noun here.

Comment: @A.Ellett [だけ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91/#jn-136029) is a word connecting to 連体形 (it's originally a noun)

Comment: @sundowner Yeah, I understand 好きな, but it's just a little weird to me when it's modifying だけ. Are there any other examples where a な word modifies だけ? Also, how should you parse だけ when it's acting as the noun here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, just to clarify, 好きなだけ is often used in a different sense:

- 好きなだけ食べなさい Eat as much as you like

This is #1 of the [大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91/#jn-136029) definition (literally: eat the amount you like):

> １ 分量・程度・限度を表す。…ほど。…くらい。…かぎり。「走れる—走ってみよう」「どれ—の人が苦しんでいるか」
>
> ２ 範囲を限定する意を表す。…ばかり。…のみ。「学校—でなく家庭での指導も大切だ」

On the other hand, your sentence used だけ in the sense of #2 'only, merely, just', which is also common enough.

Though it is categorized as 助詞, it behaves mostly like a noun: Preceding words takes 連体形 and phrases ending in だけ (本を読むのが好きなだけ here) can be followed by の.

If a na-adjective (or copula だ) precedes だけ, it ends in な (=連体形).

- この本は高価**な**だけで、あまり有用でない This book is just expensive and not so useful.
- 彼は親切**な**だけだ He is merely (being) kind.
- 彼女はまだ子供**な**だけだ She is just a child yet. (Here な is 連体形 of だ. Uttered e.g. by someone defending a girl for some foolish act).

As for the structure you can think<sup>1</sup> 本を読むのが好きなだけの極々虚弱な女の子 has the structure N1のN2, where N1=本を読むのが好きなだけ and N2=極々虚弱な女の子. A much simpler phrase with the same structure would be 黄色の本, and similarly, N1 modifies N2. Thus the sentence translates to *I'm a fairly weak girl who just likes reading books*.

---

<sup>1</sup> Forgetting だけ is a 副助詞.